# "Pop up menu is invalid" error

Tags: vb.net

After looking over several articles in internet I was not able to figure out why the following error is thrown....

I have a WIP(work in progress) grid on my home page and I have a export button which uses Infragistics and when I am trying to hit the export button and coming back to the grid and hitting anything on the grid is throwing the following error:

Message from web page
"Pop up menu is invalid"and the code is as follows:

```
//Call new page for export
string popupScriptAck = "<script language='javascript'>" +
   "window.open('ActionGridExporter.aspx?Location=" + this.Location +
   "', 'CustomPopUp', " +
   "'toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no," +
   " menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no," +
   " width=1024, height=620')" +
   "</script>";
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
   Type.GetType("System.String"),
   "PopupScriptAcknowledgement",
   popupScriptAck
);
```

Comment: That code is not JavaScript. Is it Java?

Comment: "Pop up menu is invalid" is not a javascript error.  Whatever encasing language you're using there is producing this error, it would seem.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Why would it not be? JavaScript errors can have custom messages.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, really? I'm not sure where this message would come from... it's not a default js error, I mean.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel OP's framework/library could have `new Error("Pop up menu is invalid")`. That's pretty common (for frameworks/libraries).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, You're right. I just took for granted that this was the bulk of the OP's code.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas so what could be the best solution for this....

Comment: @user1567194 Did you see my first comment? Which language is this? It's not JavaScript.

Comment: Can some one please help me with this ...

Answer (score 0):

What if `this.Location` has a single quote in it, a backslash as the last character (quite likely, and this would escape the closing quote), or even `</script>`? You need to properly URLEncode *and* javascript string escape any  strings that  become literal javascript.